# Display record in Checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table is called hobby, and the table has a couple of records. I want to bind record to a Gridview when an specified column of this gridview is a checkbox column.

How we can develop this gridview or table to have checkboxs inside a column?

Comment: Do you have any code to show us? What is the question?

Comment: Provide some code or link in support of your question. Visit here to form more detail about [how to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a repeater like the code below:

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="YourDatasource">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="YourCechbox" Checked='<%#Eval("YourfieldInDatabase") %>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Also consider the item in the table must be boolean